# Magento 2.1: how to change customer notification, worming or messages?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, localisation, messages

I have limited the number of items allowed in shopping cart to 4. That I've done successfully. however I didn't like the displayed message:

```
The most you may purchase is 4
```

I want to change it, where/how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to override `app/code/Magento/CatalogInventory/Model/StockStateProvider.php`

change the below line

```
->setMessage(__('The most you may purchase is %1.', $stockItem->getMaxSaleQty() * 1))
```

To

```
->setMessage(__('whatever message you need %1.', $stockItem->getMaxSaleQty() * 1))
```

for alternate solution you can create own module that contains a translation file i18n/en_US.csv. here you can translate your phrase

**The most you may purchase is**  to  **whatever message you need**

Comment: if i want to add any html for example link so how can i add that

Comment: without knowing context it is difficult to answer. can you please raise that separate question. @ND17

Comment: check my question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134702/how-to-add-link-in-success-message

Comment: good question! +1. Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/13840522/5528059 and change your template here "module-theme/view/frontend/templates/messages.phtml". it is common template for notification so it is not a good practice but I hope it gives some idea about sort out.

Comment: @BilalUsean, can you explain how to override that model file to new custom module pls?

Answer (score 3):

### Alternative

Another solution can be to **create a theme specific translation** by following the official documentation here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_practice.html

Then you only need to add the following in your `magento2/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/i18n/en_US.csv`:

```
'The most you may purchase is %1.','Your custom message %1'
```

Comment: found this to be a much cleaner way