# How to add link in Success message?

Tags: cart, magento-2.1, global-messages

I want to add link in cart added message

Make shopping Cart as link

In checkout cart add controller i am changing message like this

```
$message = __(
                    'You added %1 to your <a href ="..">shopping cart</a>.',
                    $product->getName()
                );
```

but its getting text when i look in console its come from knockout js and they are getting html `"html: message.text"` of message but its getting like text

How can i change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

etc\frontend\di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Message\MessageConfigurationsPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="configurationsMap" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="addProductAddSuccessMessage" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="renderer" xsi:type="const">\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Message\Renderer\BlockRenderer::CODE</item>
                <item name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">[Namespace_ModuleName]::messages/addProductSuccessMessage.phtml</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Override Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add

Replace this

```
 $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
```

with

```
$this->messageManager->addComplexSuccessMessage(
                    'addProductAddSuccessMessage',
                    [
                        'product_name' => $product->getName(),
                        'referer' => $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')->getCartUrl()
                    ]
                );
```

messages/addProductSuccessMessage.phtml

```
<?php /* @escapeVerified */ echo __('You added %1 to your ', $block->escapeHtml($block->getData('product_name'))) ?> <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('<a href="%1">shopping cart</a>.', $block->escapeUrl($block->getData('referer')));
```

Answer (score 3):

HTML is not allowed by default in flash messages and it's escaped. To change this you can use `addSuccess()` method instead of `addSuccessMessage()` to create message.

It can be done by creating plugin for`Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add` controller.
I would avoid overwriting whole `execute()` method only for this small change and rather use the following:

```
public function afterExecute()
{
    $lastAddedMessage = $this->messageManager->getMessages()->getLastAddedMessage();
    if ($lastAddedMessage && $lastAddedMessage->getType() == MessageInterface::TYPE_SUCCESS) {
        $text = $lastAddedMessage->getText();

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\Collection
         */
        $messages = $this->messageManager->getMessages();
        $messages->deleteMessageByIdentifier($lastAddedMessage->getIdentifier());

        $cartUrl = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')->getCartUrl();
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess($text . '<a href="'.$cartUrl.'">View cart</a>');
    }

    return $this->goBack();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the message using in the frontend, it is being processed via `function escapeHtml(params $allowedTags = null)` in class `\Magento\Framework\Escaper`, so it is being processed by `htmlspecialchars()` and we can't change it.