# I am trying to add link to the success message in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I am trying to add a product details link in the success message after a user clicks the add to cart button. So I create a variable in my controller but and want to send cart link. Here is file location `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart`

Here is some code from a similar question which was never solved. Can I include this with

```
if (!$this->_checkoutSession->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
                if (!$this->cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                  $cartLink = '<a href="'. $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart') .'">View Cart/Checkout</a>';
                   $message =  __('You added %1 to your shopping cart.', $product->getName()) . 
'<a  href="'.$cartLink .'">'. __('View Cart/Checkout') .'</a>';

                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
                }
```

[image]

Comment: Should check my updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try the below code in your controller its work for me

```
protected $_urlInterface;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface
) {
    $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute() {

$url = $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('checkout/cart', ['_secure' => true]);

    try{
        $message = __('You added '.$_product->getName().'to your <a href="'.$url.'">shopping cart.</a>');
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $message = __("We don't have as many %1 as you requested.",$_product->getName());
                        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($message);
    }
}
```

The result should be like this [See The Result Here](https://prnt.sc/m2y5oj)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solutions worked smoothly!

Answer (score 3):

You can try with:

```
$message =  __('You added %1 to your shopping cart.', $product->getName()) . 
'<a  href="'. $customLinkHere .'">'. __('View Cart/Checkout') .'</a>';
```

See an sample here: [\Magento\AdminNotification\Block\Grid\Renderer\Actions::render()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/AdminNotification/Block/Grid/Renderer/Actions.php#L42)

**[EDIT]**
<del>Change `addSuccessMessage()` to `addSuccess()`</del>

**[EDIT] 13 May 2018**

We should try with `addComplexSuccessMessage()`

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add"
                type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Rewrite\Cart\Add" />

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Message\MessageConfigurationsPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configurationsMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="addCartSuccessMessage" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="renderer" xsi:type="const">\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Message\Renderer\BlockRenderer::CODE</item>
                    <item name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::messages/addCartSuccessMessage.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/Controller/Rewrite/Cart/Add.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Rewrite\Cart;

class Add extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add
{
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        try {
            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = new \Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    ['locale' => $this->_objectManager->get(
                        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface::class
                    )->getLocale()]
                );
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            }
            $product = $this->_initProduct();
            $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');
            /**
             * Check product availability
             */
            if (!$product) {
                return $this->goBack();
            }
            $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            if (!empty($related)) {
                $this->cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
            }
            $this->cart->save();
            /**
             * @todo remove wishlist observer \Magento\Wishlist\Observer\AddToCart
             */
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()]
            );
            if (!$this->_checkoutSession->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
                if (!$this->cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                    if ($this->shouldRedirectToCart()) {
                        $message = __(
                            'You added %1 to your shopping cart.',
                            $product->getName()
                        );
                        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
                    } else {
                        $this->messageManager->addComplexSuccessMessage(
                            'addCartSuccessMessage',
                            [
                                'product_name' => $product->getName(),
                                'cart_url' => $this->getCartUrl(),
                            ]
                        );
                    }
                }
                return $this->goBack(null, $product);
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            if ($this->_checkoutSession->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $this->messageManager->addNotice(
                    $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class)->escapeHtml($e->getMessage())
                );
            } else {
                $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    $this->messageManager->addError(
                        $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class)->escapeHtml($message)
                    );
                }
            }
            $url = $this->_checkoutSession->getRedirectUrl(true);
            if (!$url) {
                $url = $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl($this->getCartUrl());
            }
            return $this->goBack($url);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
            return $this->goBack();
        }


    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    private function getCartUrl()
    {
        return $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart', ['_secure' => true]);
    }
    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    private function shouldRedirectToCart()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            'checkout/cart/redirect_to_cart',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/messages/addCartSuccessMessage.phtml**

```
<?php
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $block */
?>

<?= $block->escapeHtml(__(
    'You added %1 to your <a href="%2">shopping cart</a>.',
    $block->getData('product_name'),
    $block->getData('cart_url')
), ['a']);
```

[image]

We can see this commit: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/13904/files#diff-1

Comment: Khoa TruongDinh@ when I use this then I am getting error message

Comment: Khoa through showing error @  Undefined variable: customLinkHere in

Comment: Khoa through @ please see the updated question

Comment: @sanjay See my update answer: Change `addSuccessMessage()` to `addSuccess()`.

Comment: OMG!! It works!!

Comment: I'm getting a weird error - when I add to cart, I get the confirmation but with no text, just a tick.

Answer (score 0):

That will a wrong way, you just want to add text to the message after product is added to cart thus you have to modify at the place from where text is coming:-

i.e, `vendor\magento\module-checkout\Controller\Cart.php`

On line 121

```
$message = __(
              'You added %1 to your shopping cart.',
              $product->getName()
             );
```

Modify above message as you want.

Comment: I have include this line or I have to replace this with any script

Comment: You need to override the controller and replace the text, either by replacing the text or replacing $product->getName() with content you need

Comment: why we can not send  a link with a varible pass in success function , see this updated question

Comment: arushi Please see the error , I just updated question

Comment: You need to review https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134702/how-to-add-link-in-success-message link for this, Here it has explained the same think how to add a link with success message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override this file to achieve this.

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php

You can override by creating a custom module at

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Controller/Cart/Add.php

and change this part of the code:

```
if (!$this->cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                    $message = __(
                        'You added %1 to your shopping cart.',
                        $product->getName()
                    );
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
                }
```

Comment: Any other way ,

Comment: sejal @@ please see my updated question any idea , to print chekout url

Comment: @sanjay which link you wish to add ? Product detail link or cart link?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but in my case, by calling the obsolete method without "Message" solves the issue with the links.
Instead of using `addNoticeMessage`, I changed to `addNotice`, and the links were displayed.

In my case:

```
$noticeMsg = __('You must be <a href="%1">logged in</a> or <a href="%2">registered</a> to purchase these products.',
                        $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('customer/account/login'),
                        $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('customer/account/create')
                    );
$this->_messageManager->addNotice($noticeMsg);
```

Answer (score 0):

My task is, add HTML link in out of stock product message in the cart page. I have done below changes to achieve this task.

1) Override validate function and modify the message with HTML message.

```
\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Quote\Item\QuantityValidator
```

2) Override ValidationMessages(module-checkout/Block/Cart/ValidationMessages.php) block addQuoteMessages method and remove escapeHtml from the setText method.

```
$message->setText($this->escapeHtml($message->getText()));
```

Replace with

```
$message->setText($message->getText());
```

3) Last thing you need to override the Observer with your custom module and change contruct method with custom module method Test\Module\Model\Quote\Item\QuantityValidator

```
Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\QuantityValidatorObserver
```

Remove var/* generate/* and run setup:upgrade (if required then run static-content comment).

Hope the above code will help you.

Thanks.