# Add a link into error message

Tags: magento2, error, messages

How can I add a link into an error message from Message Manager ?

I have this :

```
 $physicalLink = "<a href='".$produtToAddUrl."'>".$produtToAddName."</a>";
 $this->_messageManager->addErrorMessage($physicalLink);
```

but the result is

```
<a> href='http://www.devtest.com/link.html'>link</a>
```

i need this to be an usual result (as html link)

Comment: Can you try $physicalLink = '<a href="'.$produtToAddUrl.'">'.$produtToAddName.'</a>';

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/174019/36463

Comment: This will change every message, I need it into 1 page only